# Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'value_id' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal`

Tags: magento2

While I am trying to save a product, I am getting this error:

SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'value_id' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`row_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `row_id` = VALUES(`row_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`)

How I can handle this error? I see that value_id is set as INT.

Comment: This mean that have a lot products and attributes.
And value of attributes are out of range field type ID.

Easy fix: 
open table `catalog_product_entity_decimal` ;  change type of field `value_id` to type `bigint` ; refresh cache

Answer (score 0):

There is a related issue that was reported to Magento github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28387

This issue did not resolved yet, so you can work around with one of the below temporary soluions:

- Set parametr in my.cnf: `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0`
- Implement getting the database table back in shape if you've maxed out the auto_increment: https://gist.github.com/JesKingDev/af70e92740215009ab1bebe5a2cdc17f. Remember to change the database table name in their command from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` to `catalog_product_entity_decimal` due to you have issue with `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.
- Change `value_id` column type to `bigint`:

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_decimal MODIFY value_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Value ID';
```